# What is the difference between message key and message descriptor in message passing in System V IPC?

Tags: ipc

Why is there a separate requirement of key and descriptors in message queues?

Why only key is not sufficient to describe a queue?

According to me, both are unique for a message queue, and hence only one could suffice instead of both.
The msgget function should return the key itself instead of sending a descriptior as both will be unique for a message queue